# "Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object '.x' not found" when using data.table function within purrr::map_dfr()

Tags: r, function, data.table, purrr

When I'm using a `data.table` aggregation function within `purrr::map_dfr()`, I encountered this error message `Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object '.x' not found`, but I have no clue how this error come about. Below is a minimal reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

df = as.data.table(mtcars)

ffreq = function(group, data = df){
  group = substitute(group)
  return(data[,.(N = .N),eval(group)])
}

# These functions work
ffreq('mpg')
ffreq('gear')

# This one within map_dfr does not work

d_all = map_dfr(names(df), ffreq)
# Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object '.x' not found
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The following is enough since `by` accepts character vectors:

```
ffreq = function(group, data = df) data[, .N, group]
```

Also you could do all this without `purrr`:

```
groupingsets(df, j = .N, by = names(df), sets = as.list(names(df)))
```

Or

```
rbindlist(lapply(names(df), ffreq), fill = TRUE)
```